# How do I include errors in my javascript mortgage calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, css, error-handling, event-handling

I am trying to get my calculator to throw an error when the APR exceeds 25% or less than 0.
Loan Term must be > 0 and less than or equal to 40, else an error message is displayed. I tried many ways but unable to figure it out.

APR (Annual Percentage Rate )—text input field. Give this field the name and id apr. Must allow floating point values between 0 and 25.00 % .
Loan Term (in years)—text input field. Give this field the name and id term. Must be > zero and less than or equal to 40.
Loan Amount—(in dollars) text input field. Give this field the name and id amount.

```
   <div>
<form action="">
<label> APR%: </label><br>
  <label><input type="number" id="apr" name="APR" placeholder ="Annual Percentage Rate...."/></label><br>
  <label> Loan Term: </label><br>
  <label>  <input type="number" id="term" name="APR"placeholder ="Loan Term...."/></label><br>
  <label> Loan Amount: </label><br>
  <label> <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder ="Loan Amount...."/></label><br>
  <label> Monthly Payment: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="payment" name="mPmt" placeholder ="Display Monthly Payment"/><br>
  <input type="button" onclick = "errors()" id="sbt" value="Submit" />
  <input type="reset" id="rst" value="Reset Form" />
</form>
</div>

<script>
var term;
var apr;
var amount;
var mPmt;


window.onload = function()
{
  document.getElementById("apr").focus();
  document.getElementById("sbt").onclick = getValues;
};

//use toFixed(2) to set the precision of the mPayment. Use it on an int.
function getValues()
{
  term = document.getElementById("term").value;
  apr = document.getElementById("apr").value;
  amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  apr /=1200;
  term *= 12;
  mPmt = calculatePayment();
  document.getElementById("payment").value = "$" + mPmt.toFixed(2);
};
function calculatePayment()
{
    var payment = amount*(apr * Math.pow((1 + apr), term))/(Math.pow((1 + apr), term) - 1);
    return payment;``
    }
function errors() {
var message , x;
message = document.getElementById("01");
message.innerHTML ="";
x = document.getElementById("apr").value;
try{
if (x == "") throw "empty";
if (isNaN(apr)) throw "not a number";
x = Number(x);
if (apr < 0) throw "should be a postive integer";
if (apr > 25) throw "apr can only be up to 25.00% but not less than 0";
}

catch(err) {
message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err
}

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code:

1. The element that should display the message was missing
2. The function that was supposed to check for errors was not called

```js
var term;
var apr;
var amount;
var mPmt;


window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("apr").focus();
  // adding the event handler to form submit:
  document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", submitForm)
  //document.getElementById("sbt").onclick = getValues;
};

//use toFixed(2) to set the precision of the mPayment. Use it on an int.
function getValues() {
  term = document.getElementById("term").value;
  apr = document.getElementById("apr").value;
  amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  apr /= 1200;
  term *= 12;
  mPmt = calculatePayment();
  document.getElementById("payment").value = "$" + mPmt.toFixed(2);
};

function calculatePayment() {
  var payment = amount * (apr * Math.pow((1 + apr), term)) / (Math.pow((1 + apr), term) - 1);
  return payment;
}

// create a function that is executed on form submission
function submitForm(e) {
  // you need to prevent the default action if you don't
  // want to send the form data to an API endpoint
  e.preventDefault()
  getValues()
  // your error checking function is called here
  errors()
}

function errors() {
  var message, x;
  // I added the element with ID 01 to the HTML - it was missing
  message = document.getElementById("01");
  message.innerHTML = "";
  x = document.getElementById("apr").value;
  try {
    if (x == "") throw "empty";
    if (isNaN(apr)) throw "not a number";
    x = Number(x);
    if (apr < 0) throw "should be a postive integer";
    if (apr > 25) throw "apr can only be up to 25.00% but not less than 0";
  } catch (err) {
    message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <form id="form">
    <label> APR%: </label><br>
    <label><input type="number" id="apr" name="APR" placeholder ="Annual Percentage Rate...."/></label><br>
    <label> Loan Term: </label><br>
    <label>  <input type="number" id="term" name="APR"placeholder ="Loan Term...."/></label><br>
    <label> Loan Amount: </label><br>
    <label> <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder ="Loan Amount...."/></label><br>
    <label> Monthly Payment: </label><br>
    <input type="text" id="payment" name="mPmt" placeholder="Display Monthly Payment" /><br>
    <!-- change type to submit: if you click this button
    the function defined in the event listener is going to
    be executed -->
    <input type="submit" id="sbt" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" id="rst" value="Reset Form" />
  </form>
  <div id="01"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will see how it works for me.